# jquery vertical menu popout & toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

How can I add an expand all link and collapse all links in the menu in my below fiddle example?

Also is there a way where I can popout the menu with just a menu button using media queries for smaller screens and when clicked the menu should open the side of the screen within the same example

http://jsfiddle.net/PZHF5/

```
Thanks
```

Comment: Stack Overflow's policies regarding post content are there to *help* you, not to restrict you. I assume you got a message saying something like you should not only link to jsFiddle but also include your code in the post. Then why didn't you do it instead of formatting the word "Thanks" as code? Fewer people will bother to help you if they cannot think about the problem without leaving the site. It's your loss at the end, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand / collapse all, you could add the following. Note that this does not communicate with your plugin, so it's sort of a twerky workaround. That being said, it doesn't look like you've done much to modify the code yourself. As for the responsive menu button - what have you tried?

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="xpnd">Expand all</a>
<a href="#" class="clps">Collapse all</a>
```

jQuery

```
var $ul = $('.topnav li ul'),
    $sp = $('.topnav span'),
    dur = 300;
$('.xpnd').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $ul.slideDown(dur);
    $sp.replaceWith('<span>[-]</span>');
});
$('.clps').click(function(){
    e.preventDefault();
    $ul.slideUp(dur);
    $sp.replaceWith('<span>[+]</span>');
});
```

Comment: Except for the +/- sign after a expand all click it all works...Great Work! Thanks!